# Is Azure Maps suitable for public websites

Tags: azure-maps

I've noticed that during testing we already have a lot of tiles loaded from azure maps (15k with only 5 developers/testers), which makes me wonder if this a suitable solution for public websites, or should it only be used in internal (behind a login) websites?

We use Azure Maps in combination with Leaflet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can absolutely be used in public applications. Try using 512 tiles to reduce the number of tiles being loaded (1/4th the tile requests compared to using 256 tiles). Here is a code sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/master/AzureMapsCodeSamples/Third%20Party%20Map%20Controls/Raster%20Tiles%20in%20Leaflet%20JS.html

Double check that caching is working correctly (the map tiles have a 24 hour cache header on them, so a single user will rarely generate more than a few transactions a day if they use it a lot).